# Setting parameters in scala classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xgboost

I am trying to get familiar with classes in Scala(spark) and I wrote a simple wrapper class over `XGBoostClassifier` to experiment with. Once that wrapper class was ready, I tried setting some parameters but I am getting errors and can't find much help online

This is the class I am using

```
class trialXGBClassifier{
  var xgb_cls_object: XGBoostClassifier = _
}
```

I also wrote a small utility function to convert JSON to a `Map` (string, string)

```
def jsonToMap(jsonString: String): Map[String, String] = {
  val jsonMap = JSON.parseFull(jsonString).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
  return jsonMap
  }
```

And this is the code that's giving me the error

```
var params = """{"numRound": "10"}"""
var trial_xgb = new trialXGBClassifier
trial_xgb.xgb_cls_object.setSeed(jsonToMap(params)("numRound").toLong)
```

This is the error message I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  ... 61 elided
```

I tried doing the following using the actual ml.dmlc class and it works

```
var xgb_orig = new XGBoostClassifier
xgb_orig.setSeed(jsonToMap(params)("numRound").toLong)
xgb_orig.getSeed #10
```

Whats the reason behind this error and how do I fix this?

Comment: You are never initializing  ```xgb_cls_object``` It is set to ```_``` thus when you try to call ```.setSeed ``` there is no instance of ```XGBoostClassifier``` to call the method on. You either need to construct a default one ```var xgb_cls_object = new XGBoostClassifier``` or turn it into a param, or an implicit one for that matter and have the caller pass it in

Comment: Well, thanks. I spent about an hour trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, people try to use `val` instead of `var` in all places where such usage possible. Also, they try to use `case class` or `sealed trait` instead of just `class`.
So, there's a very nice way to avoid such kind of issues using `case class`:

```
case class TrialXGBClassifier(xgb_cls_object: XGBoostClassifier)
```

And then the best option to use your wrapper only when you have something to wrap:

```
val xgb_orig = new XGBoostClassifier
xgb_orig.setSeed(jsonToMap(params)("numRound").toLong)
val v = TrialXGBClassifier(xgb_orig)
```

And you even can omit `xgb_orig` declaration:

```
val v = TrialXGBClassifier(new XGBoostClassifier)
v.xgb_cls_object.setSeed(jsonToMap(params)("numRound").toLong)
```